# When I try to convert this code to exe file it runs a cmd window

Tags: python, pyinstaller

When I try to convert this code to exe file it runs a cmd window with the title `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe`:

```
path = 'supported_languages.txt'
os.system(f'notepad.exe {path}')
```

Here is the code I use for convert it to exe file:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --windowed --icon "[ICON PATH]"  "[FILE PATH]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the extension file name from .py to .pyw